# Tkinter popup window

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have a simple UI to send SMS text messages and it looks like this:

[image]

Code:

```py
import requests
from tkinter import *


def send_message():
    to = Receiver_text.get()
    fromm = Sender_text.get()
    message = Message_entry.get(1.0,'end')
  #  message = Message_text.get()
    payload = {'to': to, 'from': fromm, 'message': message, 'email': '@email', 'api_secret': '123456789'}
    r = requests.get('https://example.com/api',params=payload)
    print(r.url)
def clear_text():
    Sender_entry.delete(0, 'end')
    Receiver_entry.delete(0, 'end')
    Message_entry.delete("1.0", "end")

#window object

app = Tk()
app.iconbitmap('a.ico')
# Sender
SR_frame = Frame(app)
Sender_text = StringVar()
Sender_label = Label(SR_frame, text='Sender: ', font=('bold', 14))
Sender_label.pack(side = 'left')
Sender_entry = Entry(SR_frame, textvariable=Sender_text, font=("Bold",14))
Sender_entry.pack(side = 'left', padx = (0, 20))
# Receiver
Receiver_text = StringVar()
Receiver_label = Label(SR_frame, text='Receiver: ', font=('bold', 14))
Receiver_label.pack(side = 'left')
Receiver_entry = Entry(SR_frame, textvariable=Receiver_text, font=("Bold",14))
Receiver_entry.pack(side = 'left')
SR_frame.pack(padx = 20)
# Message
Message_text = StringVar()
Message_label = Label(app, text='Message', font=('bold', 14))
Message_label.pack(pady = 5)
#Message_entry = Entry(app, textvariable=Message_text)
Message_entry = Text(app, width=45, height=5, font=("Bold",16))
Message_entry.pack()
# Buttons
btn_frame = Frame(app)
send_btn = Button(btn_frame, text='Send', width=16, command=send_message)
send_btn.pack(side = 'left')
clear_btn = Button(btn_frame, text='Clear', width=16, command=clear_text)
clear_btn.pack(side = 'right')
btn_frame.pack(pady = 20)
app.title('sms')
app.geometry('630x255')
#start
app.mainloop()
```

It's basically a UI that takes input from the user and sends it off as a GET request.
What i'm trying to do is create a popup window that whenever i click "send" it can show a confirmation popupbox saying "Message Sent" and a "Okay" button. I'm having issues creating a simple popup box...

Help is highly appreciated.

Comment: What are you having issues with?

Comment: I tried a bunch of times to create a popup window after pressing the "Send" button but it just doesn't work.

Comment: _"I'm having issues creating a simple popup box..."_ - what are the issues? What does "it just doesn't work" mean? Does the program crash? Is the window tiny? huge? Do you get an error? Does nothing happen at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **tkinter**, use can show a popup using the **messagebox** class.

Try this code:

```
import requests
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox  # add this line


def send_message():
    .......
    messagebox.showinfo(title="Message Sent", message="Message Sent")  # add this line
```

[image: Popup]

Comment: Holy, this is so simple. Thank you so much. I spent two hours trying and it was too complicated.